# mysql regex counting

Tags: mysql, count

```
table links
id       url
 1       http://www.domain.hk/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=8
 3       http://www.domain.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=3
 6       http://www.domain.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=8
 8       http://www.domain.hk/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=7&language=tc
 9       http://www.domain.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=3
```

How to count number of same `cPath id`  and number of same `cPath id`'s  `domain` from field `url` use `regex` ?

I want the results like this:

cPath : `8`  total: `2`  hk: `1` com : `1`

cPath : `3`  total: `2`   com : `2`

cPath : `7`  total: `1`   com : `1`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: mind to fix all the typo first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I have enough knowledge to generate `hk:1, com:1`

but this is closer I can generate

```
select 
  substring_index(substring_index(url, 'cPath=', -1), '&', 1) as cpath, 
  count(*) as total, 
  substring_index(substring_index(url, '/', 3), '.', -1) as tld 
from links 
group by cpath, tld;
```

```
| cpath | count(*) | tld  |
+-------+----------+------+
| 3     |        2 | com  |
| 7     |        1 | hk   |
| 8     |        1 | com  |
| 8     |        1 | hk   |
+-------+----------+------+
```

**PS** `hk,com` is not domain name but **TLD**